# Error handling when opening applications in python

Tags: python, file, error-handling, subprocess

I need to open a file in a specific application using python. I'm going to default to opening the file using the default app location / filename; however should the app be unable to be opened, I'd like to handle that error and give the user some other options.

I've understood so far that subprocess.call is the best way to do this, as opposed to system.os

Application: /Applications/GreatApp.app

This works fine

```
subprocess.call(['open','/Applications/GreatApp.app','placeholder.gap'])
```

However, when I start adding the try / except loops, they seem to do nothing. (note the space in the application name - I'm using the incorrect name to force an exception)

```
try:
    subprocess.call(['open','/Applications/Great App.app','placeholder.gap'])
except: 
    print 'this is an error placeholder'
```

I'll still see the following error displayed in python

```
The file /Applications/Great App.app does not exist.
```

The closest I've found to some form of error handling is the following. Is looking at the value of retcode the right way to go about this?

```
try:
    retcode = subprocess.call("open " + filename, shell=True)
    if retcode < 0:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Child was terminated by signal", -retcode
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Child returned", retcode
except OSError, e:
    print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e
```

Turns out retcode isn't the way, as both correct and incorrect names give a value greater than 0.

Comment: Yup, the retcode approach is correct. Perhaps try swapping the `subprocess.call` arguments in the final code snippet with the first one? `shell=True` results in a level of indirection, and it should be unnecessary in this case since `open` isn't a shell command.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - I looked deeper and found changing if retcode < 0: to if retcode == 1: would handle errors with the file name/path. I assume that the returncode of subprocess.call only returns 1 or 0? (edit:sp)

Comment: Shouldn't the first item in the `args` argument of a `subprocess.call()` be the application?

Comment: The retcode (or exit status code) indicates an error if it is non-zero, and success if it equals zero. I believe the error values typically range from 1-255.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Comment: @martineau on osx at least, I need to specify 'open' as the first arg. Otherwise I'll get permission denied errors. I'm going to make other functions for other os', but just used osx as the example.

Comment: Hmm, I'd think OSX would be like Linux...

Comment: I wouldn't discount the possibility that I'm wrong :P |

@jtmoulia I'll use retcode > 1 as it's going to better handle additional errors. Thanks

Comment: Cool, but you're going to want to make that `if retcode > 0: [error]`. g'luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no control over the application that the user has associated with the file I'm opening.

I need to be able to specify the application to be used and the file to be opened.

`subprocess.call` doesn't return exceptions should the application/file be unable to be opened.

It's friend `subprocess.check_call`, does.

From the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call

> If the return code was zero then return, otherwise raise
>   CalledProcessError. The CalledProcessError object will have the return
>   code in the returncode attribute.

I've provide my usage examples below for future reference

For OSX

```
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w') # Used in combination with the stdout variable
                              # to prevent output from being displayed while 
                              # the program launches.
try:
    # First try the default install location of the application
    subprocess.check_call(['open','/Applications/Application.app',filename], stdout=FNULL)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    # Then ask user to manually enter in the filepath to Application.app
    print 'unable to find /Applications/Application.app'
    # Now ask user to manually enter filepath
```

For Windows, change this line

```
subprocess.check_call(['C:\file\to\program',filename], stdout=FNULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

What does this show?

```
subprocess.call (['ls', '-l', '/Applications'])
```

The error message you got says that the application that you are trying to open does not exist.

And you won't get an exception if it doesn't as you have found.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. It will open file with its default editor, if it is installed.

```
ss=subprocess.Popen(FileName,shell=True)
ss.communicate()
```